# "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.GraphicsDevice" giving me AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, xna, access-violation

So, recently I was following a tutorial on how to make a game with FNA in Visual Studio.
Everything worked fine until I added these four lines of code (in cs):

```
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1280;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 720;
graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

Now, whenever I launch the game it gives me this error (it can be a little bit different than the one I get because I had to translate some parts of it):

```
This exception was originally thrown on this call stack:
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.GraphicsDevice (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsAdapter, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsProfile, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.PresentationParameters)
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.IGraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice ()
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DoInitialize ()
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run ()
GameEngine.Program.Main (string []) in Program.cs
```

I searched the whole internet about this, and there is no solution so far. Also, for some reason it DOES work in VSC, tho I would like to do it in VS (actually, I used the NuGet package in VSC so that might be the solution, but all the code that I'm actually using is the same).

If that somehow helps you with the solution, here is the series I was following, and I got stuck on part two: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3wErD7ZIp_DtsTKoouVCxu81UQkI9VZL

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your title shows that it's an AccessViolationException, which is described as "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt". it might be because `graphics.ApplyChanges()` is attempting to write in a protected/readonly folder. But I'm not sure if this is related with graphics code, is the game working if you remove/comment out the recently added lines of code?

Comment: @Steven Yes, it does work when I remove/comment on it. Sorry for the late reply, but I'm new to stack overflow and I did not know how to do that.

Comment: I see, is it possible the folder where it tries to write is protected or readonly? (I'm not sure if VSC saves it somewhere else than VS)